# Why does my iOS App only crashes in App Store?

Tags: ios, swift, crash, app-store-connect

Every version I've submitted via App Store Connect passes the verification process and the TestFlight version, as well as on Xcode, work fine. However, as soon as I download the app from the app store, it crashes after pressing a specific button.

I don't understand the Crash Log. The only thing I've added to it, is a trial version, where I write a date to the Key Chain and check if it's been 7 days since the first download or not. The in-App subscription that get's checked during that button press shouldn't be causing the issue, because it worked before. I did end up creating a new in-app subscription to be sure.

So basically I check if the app's been installed before and then enable/disable features and pop the subscription screen if the trial has ended.

[image of what should happen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obRIw.png)

Instead, it just crashes on that screen.

Here is what I do:

```
func trialCheck() {
    // creating a keychain
    let keychain = Keychain()
    let timestamp = Date()
    
    //Adding to keychain
    keychain["my_keychain_name"] = "123456"
    
    // Checking Creation Date
    let creationDate = keychain[attributes: "my_keychain_name"]?.creationDate
    
    //Format differece between creation and timestamp to minutes
    let diffComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.second], from: creationDate!, to: timestamp)
    //let hours = diffComponents.hour
    let secondsAfterFirstInstall = diffComponents.second!
    //let test_seconds = 700000
    
    // What to do if over 7 days
    if secondsAfterFirstInstall > 604800 {
        trialLabel.text = "Your Trial Has Ended"
    }
    else {
        // Format text to show how many days + hours trial is left
        let interval = 604800 - secondsAfterFirstInstall

        let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
        formatter.allowedUnits = [.day, .hour]
        formatter.unitsStyle = .full

        let formattedString = formatter.string(from: TimeInterval(interval))!
        //print(formattedString)
        trialLabel.text = "Free Trial: " + formattedString
        
        // Actions to enable features while in trial
        // For Preview Recording
        listenButton.isEnabled = true
        micButton.isEnabled = false
        //unlockButton.isHidden = true
        pairViaQRCodeButton.isEnabled = true
    }
    
}
```

Here's the Crash log I get, when using the app (only App Store version):
Please help me out, I've resubmitted over 10 times

```
{"app_name":"Babyphone","timestamp":"2021-01-18 17:08:25.00 +0100","app_version":"1.82","slice_uuid":"abd9ae9f-888c-3559-b877-8e2dac8c94d4","adam_id":1534587849,"build_version":"3","platform":2,"bundleID":"com.meier.BabyphoneApp","share_with_app_devs":0,"is_first_party":0,"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 14.3 (18C66)","incident_id":"CE831135-D604-4C34-80FD-D1E2F9D8E452","name":"Babyphone"}
Incident Identifier: CE831135-D604-4C34-80FD-D1E2F9D8E452
CrashReporter Key:   a27fd0ee501979c2ec25fb64701f6e8d5dd60e1f
Hardware Model:      iPhone13,2
Process:             Babyphone [979]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/0B84FD57-3FB5-43B0-8288-DF28650CB872/Babyphone.app/Babyphone
Identifier:          com.meier.BabyphoneApp
Version:             3 (1.82)
AppStoreTools:       12C29
AppVariant:          1:iPhone13,2:14
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.meier.BabyphoneApp [597]


Date/Time:           2021-01-18 17:08:25.3941 +0100
Launch Time:         2021-01-18 17:07:43.9274 +0100
OS Version:          iPhone OS 14.3 (18C66)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    1.31.03-5
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  7

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x1a0ab186c 0x1b5a20c50 0x1b5cc8208 0x1b5cc84e8 0x1a38c0df0 0x1a38c0b98 0x1a38bfd34 0x1a38c1344 0x1a38b4b64 0x1a38b51ec 0x1b5ce3304 0x1018997ac 0x101898a64 0x100eecc14 0x100eef194 0x10189c538 0x101899170 0x1a10cef18 0x1a10e1548 0x1a06a424c 0x1a06a5db0 0x1a06ad10c 0x1a06adc90 0x1a06b7d78 0x1ec283804 0x1ec28a75c)

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001ce8042d0 0x1ce800000 + 17104
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001ce803660 0x1ce800000 + 13920
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a0a2cc30 0x1a098c000 + 658480
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a0a26c14 0x1a098c000 + 633876
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a0a2621c 0x1a098c000 + 631324
5   GraphicsServices                0x00000001b852a784 0x1b8527000 + 14212
6   UIKitCore                       0x00000001a3464fe0 0x1a289c000 + 12357600
7   UIKitCore                       0x00000001a346a854 0x1a289c000 + 12380244
8   Babyphone                       0x0000000100ee1dc8 0x100ed8000 + 40392
9   libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001a06e66b0 0x1a06e5000 + 5808

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.utility-qos
Thread 1:
0   libswiftCore.dylib              0x00000001a4a39b8c 0x1a469f000 + 3779468
1   libswiftCore.dylib              0x00000001a4a39cb4 0x1a469f000 + 3779764
2   libswiftCore.dylib              0x00000001a4a399e0 0x1a469f000 + 3779040
3   AttributeGraph                  0x00000001c9dad088 0x1c9d9b000 + 73864
4   AttributeGraph                  0x00000001c9d9eb40 0x1c9d9b000 + 15168
5   AttributeGraph                  0x00000001c9d9e2ec 0x1c9d9b000 + 13036
6   AttributeGraph                  0x00000001c9dae18c 0x1c9d9b000 + 78220
7   AttributeGraph                  0x00000001c9daf558 0x1c9d9b000 + 83288
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a06a5db0 0x1a06a2000 + 15792
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a06b6a68 0x1a06a2000 + 84584
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a06b7120 0x1a06a2000 + 86304
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001ec2837c8 0x1ec280000 + 14280
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001ec28a75c 0x1ec280000 + 42844

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001ec28a754 0x1ec280000 + 42836

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001ec28a754 0x1ec280000 + 42836

Thread 4 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001ce8042d0 0x1ce800000 + 17104
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001ce803660 0x1ce800000 + 13920
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a0a2cc30 0x1a098c000 + 658480
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a0a26c14 0x1a098c000 + 633876
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a0a2621c 0x1a098c000 + 631324
5   Foundation                      0x00000001a1cd5df0 0x1a1ccd000 + 36336
6   Foundation                      0x00000001a1cd5cbc 0x1a1ccd000 + 36028
7   UIKitCore                       0x00000001a3518d48 0x1a289c000 + 13094216
8   Foundation                      0x00000001a1e47a34 0x1a1ccd000 + 1550900
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001ec281b40 0x1ec280000 + 6976
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001ec28a768 0x1ec280000 + 42856

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001ec28a754 0x1ec280000 + 42836

Thread 6 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001ce8042d0 0x1ce800000 + 17104
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001ce803660 0x1ce800000 + 13920
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a0a2cc30 0x1a098c000 + 658480
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a0a26c14 0x1a098c000 + 633876
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a0a2621c 0x1a098c000 + 631324
5   CFNetwork                       0x00000001a12fc2c0 0x1a10b0000 + 2409152
6   Foundation                      0x00000001a1e47a34 0x1a1ccd000 + 1550900
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001ec281b40 0x1ec280000 + 6976
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001ec28a768 0x1ec280000 + 42856

Thread 7 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.NSURLSession-delegate
Thread 7 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001ce828414 0x1ce800000 + 164884
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001ec282b40 0x1ec280000 + 11072
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001a9e4eb74 0x1a9dd8000 + 486260
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001b5b26cf8 0x1b5b13000 + 81144
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001b5b17e4c 0x1b5b13000 + 20044
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001b5a20f64 0x1b5a1a000 + 28516
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001b5b260e0 0x1b5b13000 + 78048
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001b5b2606c 0x1b5b13000 + 77932
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a06a5dc4 0x1a06a2000 + 15812
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a06ad10c 0x1a06a2000 + 45324
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a06adc90 0x1a06a2000 + 48272
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a06b7d78 0x1a06a2000 + 89464
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001ec283804 0x1ec280000 + 14340
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001ec28a75c 0x1ec280000 + 42844
```

Comment: On the first load is the keychain creationDate defined ? In the log, the error seems related to NSURLSession delegate : thread 7

Comment: Symbolicate the crash log to determine where your app has crashed.  The actual crash appears to be in the URL session delegate and the code you have shown is not performing any URL operation. Finding out what it was doing in thread 0 will give you a clue as to where in your code the app was.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing anything else, seeing

```
let creationDate = keychain[attributes: "my_keychain_name"]?.creationDate
```

and then

```
let diffComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.second], from: creationDate!, to: timestamp)
```

seems like a great opportunity for a crash if creationDate == nil. Try checking that creationDate is valid before using it, i.e.,

```
if let creationDate = ... { ... }
```

or

```
guard let creationDate = ... else { ... }
```

depending on what you want to do if it's not.